# Set visibility of Views in a Gallery - Android

Tags: android, gallery

I have extended the `android.widget.Gallery` to add some functionality. One of the functionality is that i need in some situations to show only certain items. For this, here is what i have done.

```
public void displayChildViews(Integer... indices) {

    boolean showAll = indices.length == 0;

    if (indices.length > this.getChildCount())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format(
                        "Number of indices (%d) cannot be larger then the gallery child count (%d)",
                        indices.length, this.getCount()));

    List<Integer> showIndices = Arrays.asList(indices);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        int visibility = showAll || showIndices.contains(i) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
        this.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(visibility);
    }       
}
```

This is my Problem. First, I tried to iterate through children using the `this.getChildCount()` but it only returned the number of the visible items (in my case, images) and did not return the number of all the child items of the gallery. So to overcome this, I used `this.getCount` which returns the correct number of child items (according to the adapter). The thing is that i need to set the visibility of all the child items but the `this.getChildAt(i)` return the i-th child of the **visible** child items and not the true child item with the proper index. Any one now a way to get the true i-th child?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of manipulating galley items, do the changes in adapter associated with the galley. Remove the items you don want to display from Adapter and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: This is the thing i'm trying to avoid. I have extended a `HorizontalScrollView` that when the users scrolls it notifies its listeners (in my case, the gallery). When the user scrolls, then the selected item should be the only item visible in the gallery but if the user scrolls back, the rest of the images should re-appear. This is why i don't want to change the gallery data set but only manipulate the visibility of the items. - If there is no other way, of course ill change the adapter.

Comment: This is the way all the AdpaterView Works it simply reuse the items. So in order to change gallery items you should manipulate the Adpater.